# iPhone SDK Auto scrolling UIWebView to a specific position

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I Have a UIWebView that displays third party web page (not a page I can control)
I need a way to scroll the content of the web view to a specific position in that page.
Any idea how to implement it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, hate to answer my own question but it was easier then I thought...

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.scrollBy(0,180);"];

Comment: you should accept your own answer too! I found this helpful. Thanks!